# Pyautogui typewrite() really slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm making a bot to play Nitro Type for me. I'm using Pyautogui typewrite() to type out the text but it is way slower than it should be. Without a time.sleep() added to it, it is only typing at 111 WPM when. Then when I add the delay which is set to 0.019546153826607692 it gets 70 I'm pretty sure it is my fault but I don't know what I did wrong any help would be appreciated. Oh and here is the code for that part of it.

```
for i in range(1):
    driver.get('https://www.nitrotype.com/race')
    time.sleep(5)
    html = driver.page_source.replace('&nbsp;', ' ')
    f = open("word.html", "w")
    f.write(html)
    f.close()

    with open("word.html", "r") as html_file:
        content = html_file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    words = soup.find_all('span', class_='dash-letter')
    stuff = ""
    for span in words:
        if span.text.isascii():
            stuff += span.text
    with open("Sentence.txt", "w") as wf:
        wf.write(stuff)
    wf.close()

    e = open('Sentence.txt', 'r')
    s = e.read()
    Words = len(s.split())
    Characters = len(s)
    delay1 = (WPM * Characters) / Words
    delay2 = delay1 / 60
    delay3 = Characters / delay2
    Delay = (delay3 / Characters)
    print(Delay)
    for word in s:
        pyautogui.typewrite(word)
        time.sleep(Delay)
```

Comment: I think you meant, `for word in s.split():` on the 3rd last line.

Comment: So (for word in Words:)

Comment: But `Words` is not a list, its a int

Comment: wait it says s.split() is not iterable

Comment: Not sure why it says that.

Comment: Well wouldn't it be an integer too it's the length of a sentence